# How to understand this Pyomo Constraint (rewriting the constraint)

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to Pyomo.

I wrote this constraint in Pyomo written below as shown in this equation:

[image]

```
model.amount_of_energy_con = pe.ConstraintList()
for t in model.time:
    for b in model.boats:
        for s in model.chargers:
            lhs = model.charge_energy[b, t, s]
            rhs = model.c_rating[s] * model.boat_battery_capacity * model.boats_availability[b][t] * model.charging[b, t, s]
            model.amount_of_energy_con.add(expr= (lhs <= rhs))
```

For the Constraint above, I think my constraint should be something like this in the model object

```
Key : Lower : Body                  :  Upper                  : Active
1 :  -Inf   : charge_energy[1,0,SC] :  15.75*charging[1,0,SC] : True
2 :  -Inf   : charge_energy[1,0,FC] :  126*charging[1,0,FC]   : True
```

But I was getting this below using `model.amount_of_energy_con.pprint()`

```
Key : Lower : Body                                           : Upper : Active
1 :  -Inf   : charge_energy[1,0,SC] - 15.75*charging[1,0,SC] : 0.0   : True
2 :  -Inf   : charge_energy[1,0,FC] - 126*charging[1,0,FC]   : 0.0   : True
```

Note: The 0 in the equation was added as bounds when setting up the model.charge_energy Variable `model.charge_energy = pe.Var(model.boats, model.time, model.chargers, bounds=(0, None))` and I still don't understand why my Lower is -Inf.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The 2 versions of the constraint you post are mathematically equivalent.  It is standard form to bring the variables into the body, instead of the RHS.  The constraint does not proscribe a lower bound, so the default is -inf.  If you put that bound in at variable creation, as I previously suggested, you should see that when you `pprint` the variable, or the entire model.  I think yer GTG.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the lower bound is 0 in my charge_energy variable. 

```
Key            : Lower :  Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
(1, 0, 'FC') :     0     :  None :  None : False :  True  : NonNegativeIntegers
(1, 0, 'SC') :     0.    :  None :  None : False :  True  : NonNegativeIntegers
```

Thank you so much @AirSquid.